# Filtering for Wright-Fisher HMM

Tags: kalman-filters, filtering, hmm

I am trying to understand what filter may be suitable for the following HMM:

The signal is a Wright-Fisher one-dimensional diffusion characterised by the SDE

$$dX_{t}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\alpha(1-x)-\beta x\right)dt+\sqrt{X_{t}(1-X_{t})}dB_{t}$$

with unknown parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$. This process has stationary distribution $\mathrm{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$. At discrete times Binomial observations are sampled conditionally on the value of the process $X_{t}=x$, $f_{Y_{t}}(y;x)=\text{Bin}(y,N;x)$.

Comment: what a cool problem.  so $X_t$ is bound on $[0 1]$  a binomial would have a probability of success.  Could you elaborate on the observations?

Comment: Alright, then observations are drawn at discrete times (random) with distribution $\mathbb{P}(Y_{t}=y|X_{t}=x)=\binom{N}{y}x^{y}(1-x)^{N-y}$. I guess I should first make inference on the parameters of the diffusion ($\alpha$ and $\beta$), and then move forward with a particle filter, but that's just a guess.

Comment: what is $N$ related to? N possible observations?

Comment: Exactly, and it's arbitrary.

Comment: Arbitrary as  ? 1)  N unknown but some value N,  2)  N random with a prior distribution.  or 3)  a N $in$ ( 0 ,1, 2, 3,  ...)  or a family of sampling distributions.  It seems like you need to have some idea of N to solve this.

Comment: It is fixed, given ex-ante and it does not vary over the simulation. Let's say $N\in \{1,2,\dots,20\}$. You know that at any discrete times $\{t_{1},\dots,t_{n}\}$ you have N observations drawn from a binomial distribution.